# Rendering a view in PDF context - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, swiftui

I am trying to convert my view with lots of shapes and text to a PDF that the user can export from my app. I am having real issues with the PDF exporting and I can't find much help to do with SwiftUI. I have been given the feedback:

> "You don't need controller for that, you can just render view-by-view
> in same PDF context"

however I do not know what that means or how I would achieve it, my code for the PDF generation is below.

```
let width: CGFloat = 8.5 * 72.0
    //Estimate the height of your view
    let height: CGFloat = 1000
    let charts = MatchReportView(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam)

let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: charts)
pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

//Render the view behind all other views
let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)

//Render the PDF
let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: height))
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     do {
         try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
            context.beginPage()
            pdfVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)

         })
         print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
     } catch {
         print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
 }

pdfVC.removeFromParent()
pdfVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Any ideas on how I would get this PDF to generate? At the moment it is just returning a blank document. Will the fact it is a scroll view play a part?

Comment: Why are you removing `pdfVC` from it's parent and removing its view from the superview at the end?

Comment: This is just the code I found through another stack overflow post, so I'm not sure!

Comment: Just commenting those lines out worked! Thank you so much!